# How to make responsive this contact form?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, responsive

I would like to make the contact form (it is in this page on my website: https://nadiasabridietista.it/contatti/ ) responsive, for example for smartphones. I tried with:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
#form_contatto{
    height: 710px;
    border-spacing: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#cont_1 {
    border-spacing: 1px;
}

#cont_2 {
    border-spacing: 0px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 15px;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

}
```

```html
}
```

but it does not work (from smartphone the form has same sizes like the desktop version).

Comment: You may wish to look into frameworks like Bootstrap that largely take the headache of responsiveness out. It's generally considered bad practice to rely on the browser pixel width/height alone.

Comment: @AStopher "*It's generally considered bad practice to rely on the browser pixel width/height alone*" Just wondering what exactly you mean by this? It's a pretty standard way of implementing media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some changes in different places:

1. `#form_contatto`

   - Remove the `margin-left`
   - Make the `width: 100%;`
2. `form`

   - remove the `max-width: 400px;`

It may need more margins and paddings for better looking, but this is the basic steps for getting it responsive.

As @AStopher mentioned, you can check the [Bootstrap Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) to make responsiveness work easier

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But if I remove the margin-left and edit the width, the form on the desktop version appears on the left and tight...

Comment: There is a `margin: auto` in an another CSS class which will make it at the center. If not, you can add the `margin: auto`

Comment: Did you remove the `max-width: 400px;` as mentioned above?

Comment: No I meant the other one (I think you can remove them both): https://imgur.com/nCspKaB

Comment: Oh, i checked and "form" also belongs to another thing on another page! Thank you, now it works.